# Ubuntu 18.04 showing laptop-NOTEBOOK in network

Tags: networking, xubuntu

Okay this might sound weird but I did a fresh install after struggling with various issues with Ubuntu 18.04. I saw the "Other Locations" in the file explorer and I saw My laptopname-NOTEBOOK in the network. Not sure what happened there and I also saw my laptop name on my android mobile file explorer while exploring devices on my home network.
That was weird, anyone here knows what might switch this off ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove nautilus-share:

```
sudo apt purge nautilus-share
```

and disable `Sharing` in Ubuntu System Settings.

[image]

Additionally read [Nautilus-share, fixing or removing?](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/nautilus-share-fixing-or-removing/3763) and [The default File Sharing and Media Sharing experience in 18.04](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/the-default-file-sharing-and-media-sharing-experience-in-18-04/3834).